# Exception when running instrumented tests with Hilt and App Startup

Tags: android, automated-tests, dagger-hilt, android-instrumentation, app-startup

I am starting to setup some instrumented tests on my project, but when I run them, I get the following exception on logcat:

```
2022-04-11 10:41:09.352 24409-24409/com.example.appstartupinstrumentationtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.appstartupinstrumentationtest, PID: 24409
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component was not created. Check that you have added the HiltAndroidRule.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:8195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7546)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:301)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component was not created. Check that you have added the HiltAndroidRule.
        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:162)
        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:198)
        at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:38)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2429)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2399)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:8190)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7546) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:301) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component was not created. Check that you have added the HiltAndroidRule.
        at dagger.hilt.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:83)
        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.TestApplicationComponentManager.generatedComponent(TestApplicationComponentManager.java:96)
        at dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltTestApplication.generatedComponent(HiltTestApplication.java:49)
        at dagger.hilt.EntryPoints.get(EntryPoints.java:59)
        at dagger.hilt.android.EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(EntryPointAccessors.kt:35)
        at com.example.appstartupinstrumentationtest.InitializerEntryPoint$Companion.resolve(InitializerEntryPoint.kt:20)
        at com.example.appstartupinstrumentationtest.SomeComponentInitializer.create(SomeComponentInitializer.kt:10)
        at com.example.appstartupinstrumentationtest.SomeComponentInitializer.create(SomeComponentInitializer.kt:7)
        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:155)
        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:198) 
        at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:38) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2429) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2399) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:8190) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7546) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:301) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

My real codebase is much more complex, but I created a much simpler project where I am able to reproduce the issue [HERE](https://github.com/ampeixoto/app-startup-hilt-example/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/appstartupinstrumentationtest).

From what I understood, when running the instrumentation tests, the startup code is first executed, even before anything on the test class (before @Before and @BeforeClass methods).

What is the best way to handle this?